# aws EC2 install SSL certificate from Godaddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, terminal, ssl-certificate

Hello I'm trying to install my SSL certificate from GoDaddy, I expended a lot of days on this but I couldn't install it.

I modify the ssl.conf and I put this lines:

`SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/GODADYCERT.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/gd_bundle-xxxx.crt`

But when I restart httpd service, can't restart.

Any can help me?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  "Can't restart" is not sufficient.  What is the error? What did you find in the logs?

Comment: You'd probably get better answers on ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Ensure that you have installed mod_ssl and it is running.
- Upload your certificates on Instance say /home/ec2-user/ssl
- Edit /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
- check for lines and replace accordingly, listed below

  - SSLCertificateFile Location.crt
  - SSLCertificateKeyFile Location.key
  - SSLCACertificateFile Location.crt
- Restart Apache